Java parallel stream issue
I have a piece of code that works as expected in a synchronized manner but not as expected in parallel,
I have a method to fetch some items from an endpoint, the method receives a list of item numbers.
For the sake of performance, I want to divide the input list into chunks and call the backend with these sublists
public List<ItemDto> callBackend(List<String> itemNumbers) {    
try {

  int chunkSize = 10;
  var endExclusive = (itemNumbers.size() + chunkSize - 1) / chunkSize;

  return IntStream.range(0, endExclusive)
      .mapToObj(i -> itemNumbers.subList(i * chunkSize, Math.min((i + 1) * chunkSize, itemNumbers.size())))
      .parallel()
      .map(chunk -> apiClient.getItemInfo(chunk))
      .flatMap(List::stream)
      .toList();

} catch (Exception e) {
  log.error("Error", e);
  return List.of();
}
}

Unit-test
List<String> items = IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end).mapToObj(x -> "item-" + x).toList();

ArgumentCaptor<List<String>> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class);

when(apiClient.getItemInfo(argumentCaptor.capture()))
    .thenAnswer(invocationOnMock -> {
      System.out.println(argumentCaptor.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
      Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
      return argumentCaptor.getValue().stream().map(x -> ItemDto.builder().itemNumber(x).build()).toList();
    });

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
var itemDtos = unitUnderTest.callBackend(items);
long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

System.out.println("Duration: " + duration);

items.forEach(x -> {
  var list = itemDtos.stream().filter(y -> y.getItemNumber().equals(x)).toList();
  
  if (list.size() > 1) {
    System.out.println("Item number: " + x + " is duplicated");        
  }
  assertEquals(1, list.size());
});
assertEquals(items.size(), itemDtos.size());
verify(apiClient, times(items.size() / 10 + 1)).getItemInfo(anyList());

The problem: if I remove the parallel(), the test passes and the result is as expected. but if I put the parallel() back in place then the API gets called (as many as expected) but with duplicate chunks (sublist) randomly, sometimes the first chunk sometimes with one other chunk.
I tried the same approach with ForkAndJoin and some also iterating over chunks with CompletableFuture but the results were the same. I don't understand why this behavior is happening.
any idea how to solve this problem?
This issue always happens when the size of the input list is not a factor of 10 (the chunk size).

Just a sidenote, the pattern 'catch exception, log it, return an empty list' is horrible. Stop it. 1 error causes magical nothingness to occur (a user is less frustrated seeing an ugly weird unintelligible error message than stone cold nothing happening, think about it. Neither is 'good', but "nothing happens" is far worse than "this error happens that I do not understand as end user").

@rzwitserloot thanks for the sidenote, actually the code is simplified to demo the main problem

You haven't shown apiClient.getItemInfo (may not be thread-safe), nor what/where and exception is.

@DuncG thanks for your comment, apiClient is thread-safe since it is completely stateless, receives data, builds up params for RestTemplate, and returns exchange result.

I have doubts that you can use ArgumentCaptor in this way. It’s getValue() doc says: “If verified method was called multiple times then this method it returns the latest captured value.” but what does “latest” mean in the context of concurrent calls? It’s not clear why you use it at all; as far as I know, just invocationOnMock.getArgument(0) would give you the argument, without the need for an ArgumentCaptor

@Holger thanks, you are right, the ArgumentCaptor was the problem
